# using Eclipse to develop for embedded Linux on a Windows host

Tags: windows, ubuntu, eclipse-cdt, cross-compiling, embedded-linux

I got a question of using Eclipse to develop for embedded Linux on a Windows host
Here are now I have and where I am.
1. a Windows host that have the latest Eclipse + CDT (c/c++ development tools) installed
2. a Ubuntu host (ssh + samba installed) that contains sources and toolschain to build the project. (the windows and ubuntu hosts are sitting within one network segment (In LAN).)
3. I can use the following commands to build this project under Ubuntu.
    # chroot dummyroot
    # cd /home/project/Build
    # sh Build `date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`
4. I am now trying to create an eclipse C++ project to achieve the goad of the step 3, but I have been stuck here for a while. any ideas of how it can be done?

Answer (score 1):

Speaking from experience, attempting to develop embedded Linux on a Windows host is a world of pain and frustration.  Emphasis on *attempting* -- I'd like to meet someone who completed a serious project in this way, or who can explain how working in Windows made job easier.

Windows can be a great development environment for many tasks, but it's a lousy, lousy environment for embedded Linux.  There are tools out there to help you do this, but everything is much harder compared to working on a Linux host.  The toolchains are older and buggier.  You will constantly fight with your crosscompilers and GNU autotools trying to get packages to compile.  (Wait till you try to compile one of the many packages that needs to build an intermediate binary and then executes that as part of its build process.)

You probably have reasons for keeping your desktop in Windows -- just run a Linux virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse CDT can execute arbitrary commands, such as

> ssh username@target build_script

using the external builder. If you are using gcc on the target eclipse cdt can parse the output of the gcc and make from the ssh session and send you to the correct source path (if that path matches the path generated by gcc). Although this might not work windows->linux

Answer (score -1):

With Embedded Linux, I've attempted to run Virtual Machines using Ubunutu, Xubutunu, Debian. I have been developing for a long time. I design hardware and develop low level firmware, to test said hardware. I cannot get anything to work on instructions given, as in an unified IDE and development system such as I am used to (i.e. Codewarrior, MPLAB, Code Composer) If Embedded Linux is so useful and easy how is it I cannot get a single one of instructions from Yocto, Freescale, Timesys, anywhere to work? Every-time there is a directory change, or a directory that no longer exists, or even a file that is not there. Surely there something that I can use..